# Multiple text comparison algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, text, comparison

Given multiple texts that are slightly different from one another (some words missing / replaced by other words), is there a good algorithm to create some sort of "template" out of them? For example:

```
Input:
 - Hello my name is Bob
 - Hi my name is Bob
 - Hi my name is John

Output:
 - * my name is *
```

The algorithm should be as tolerant as possible to outliers, for example if I add a fourth input:

```
- Hello i am Bob
```

It should not affect the result too much.

Comment: Search for frequently occurring substrings?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar problem in biology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_sequence

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would implement it. It is not fancy or using best approuch, but does the trick!

I used java for implementation and you can extract the algorithm from it.

```
public static String matchText(List<String> textsSet)
{
    double maxWeight = 0;
    String subStringMaxWeight = "";

    // create a table to store all substring occurrences
    Hashtable<String, Integer> subStringsSet = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

    // starts a loop through text's list
    for (String text : textsSet)
    {
        // splits text into words (separeted by spaces)
        String[] subStrings = text.split(" ");
        // if text has more than 1 word, then we are considering it as a "phrase"
        if (subStrings.length > 1)
        {
            // starts a loop to generate all possible word combination
            // "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee" text will generate these combinations:
            //  aaa bbb
            //  aaa bbb ccc
            //  aaa bbb ccc ddd
            //  aaa bbb ccc ddd eee
            //      bbb ccc
            //      bbb ccc ddd
            //      bbb ccc ddd eee
            //          ccc ddd
            //          ccc ddd eee
            //              ddd eee
            for (int posIni = 0; posIni < subStrings.length-1; posIni++)
            {
                for (int posEnd = posIni + 1; posEnd < subStrings.length; posEnd++)
                {
                    StringBuilder subString = new StringBuilder();

                    // if posIni is not the first word, adds * at the begining
                    if (posIni > 0)
                        subString.append("*");

                    // generate the substring from posIni to posEnd
                    for (int pos = posIni; pos <= posEnd; pos++)
                    {
                        if (subString.length() > 0)
                            subString.append(" ");
                        subString.append(subStrings[pos]);
                    }

                    // if posEnd is not the last word, adds * at the end
                    if (posEnd < subStrings.length - 1)
                        subString.append(" *");

                    // check if substring already exists in the Hashtable                       
                    Integer counter = subStringsSet.get(subString.toString());
                    if (counter == null)
                    {
                        // substring does not exist, so stores it with the counter = 1
                        counter = new Integer(1);
                        subStringsSet.put(subString.toString(), counter);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // substring exists, so increments it's counter
                        subStringsSet.remove(subString.toString());
                        counter = new Integer(counter.intValue() + 1);
                        subStringsSet.put(subString.toString(), counter);
                    }

                    // calculate the weight of the substring based on the number of occurrences plus weight based on the number of words.
                    // counter has heavier weight, but the number of words also has some weight (defined here as 0.05 - feel free to change it)
                    double weight = counter.intValue() + ((posEnd - posIni + 1) * 0.05);
                    if (weight > maxWeight)
                    {
                        maxWeight = weight;
                        subStringMaxWeight = subString.toString();
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
    // returns the substring
    return subStringMaxWeight;
```

Comment: Nice algorthm for all permutations of a given string but in my oppionion nit the solution of the problem.